# How to control this function with the click button in java script

Tags: javascript

```
#one:hover{ border-radius: 200px; transition: all 5s; transition-timing-function: ease-in-out; transform: rotatey(540deg) }
```

I want to control this function with the javascript click. Please tells me how to call this function in javascript.

Comment: Where's your JavaScript code?

Answer (score 0):

Another example on how to change the color of an element:

```html
<h3 onclick="myFunction(this, 'red')">Click me to change my color.</h3>

<script>
function myFunction(element, color) {
  element.style.color = color;
}
</script>
```

[source](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp)

Comment: but I want to use the transition properties of this hover class on click with java script.